# AI / Automatic assisted mask with face/body detection for clone effect video?

Tags: video, video-editor, final-cut-pro-x, mask

I'd like to very closely mask my head for this 'clone effect' multilayered camera shot.

Is there an efficient tool I can use which will detect a human figure/face and mask based on that?

Should I just use the motion tracking within FCP and assign the transform of a spherical head shaped draw mask to that tracker?

How best can I 'cut out' my head/body against the background footage to sell the clone illusion? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using After Effects and the built in [RotoBrush](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/roto-brush-refine-matte.html) tool.

Apply Rotobrush to each overlaying layer to make the layers behave naturally with each other.

It will take some time, but I reckon it's what is usually used to make videos like this.

[Runway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfMJTXVQezE) also has some very cool looking AI rotobrush-type tools, but I haven't used them.

Answer (score 1):

I would break up the mask into a couple of pieces. Easier to handle the fine-tuning.
There are plugins that can track this. You have to try and see which works best.
Rotoscoping is still one of the things that need a lot of work by hand. Sometimes it's just you have to sit and do it.